# Get all input values from each table

Tags: jquery

I want to get all the values ​​of the inputs of each table in the body to later use it as json. I tried in various ways but only manage to read the first row of each table. I also tried with .serialize and .serializeArray but the result it complicates my reading a bit.

html code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ogakn9mz/

jquery code:

```
function newattr(){
    
    var attr_tag,opt_name,opt_price,opt_stock;
    
    $('body').find('table').each(function() {
    
      attr_tag = $(this).closest("div").find('input[name="attr_name"]').val();
      
      opt_name = $(this).find('input[name="opt_name"]').val();
      opt_price = $(this).find('input[name="opt_price"]').val();
      opt_stock = $(this).find('input[name="opt_stock"]').val();
      
      console.log(attr_tag+'/'+opt_name+'/'+opt_price+'/'+opt_stock);

    });
      
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
    "attributes": [
      {
        "attr_name": "Size",  
        "data":[
          {
          "opt_name": "Small",
          "opt_price": "11",
          "opt_stock":"22"
          },
          {
          "opt_name": "Medium",
          "opt_price": "33",
          "opt_stock":"44"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "attr_name": "Color",  
        "data":[
          {
          "opt_name": "Blue",
          "opt_price": "55",
          "opt_stock":"66"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through `attributes` div then inside this iterate through your `table` and push your value of input in *JSON Object*  and finally pass them to *JSON Array* .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var outer = {}; //for outer array
outer["attributes"] = new Array()
//loop through attributes div
$('body').find('.attributes').each(function() {
  var attribute_name = $(this).find('input[name="attr_name"]').val()
  var data = [] //for all table
  //loop through table tr
  $(this).find(".options_table tbody tr").each(function() {
    opt_name = $(this).find('input[name="opt_name"]').val();
    opt_price = $(this).find('input[name="opt_price"]').val();
    opt_stock = $(this).find('input[name="opt_stock"]').val();
    data.push({
      "opt_name": opt_name,
      "opt_price": opt_price,
      "opt_stock": opt_stock
    }) //push data in data array

  })

  outer["attributes"].push({
    "attr_name": attribute_name,
    "data": data //passs here
  })
});
console.log(outer)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="attributes" style="width:100%;display: inline-block;">
  <input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="attr_name" value="Size" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
  <table class="options_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_name" value="Small" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
        <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_price" value="11" maxlength="12" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
        <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_stock" value="22" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_name" value="Medium" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
        <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_price" value="33" maxlength="12" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
        <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_stock" value="44" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="attributes" style="width:100%;display: inline-block;">
  <input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="attr_name" value="Color" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
  <table class="options_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_name" value="Blue" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
      <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_price" value="55" maxlength="12" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
      <td><input class="attr_input" type="text" style="display:block;width: 100%;" name="opt_stock" value="66" maxlength="6" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false"></td>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked wonderfully. May life bless you with many tacos. Greetings from Mexico!

Comment: Glad i was able to help :)